# How to get one month in seconds

Tags: go

Failing to do something fairly simple and can't find an answer
nor from uncle Google nor from here

I'm trying to get one full month in seconds (an int)
Something more elegant then this:

```
    s := 3600 * 24 * 30
```

also tried :

```
    m := time.Hour * 24 * 30
```

but that returns type 'time.Duration' which I also can't convert to an int

NOTE: Don't really care for the pressie days of each month (28-31)
but if it's possible to use specific month as input it will be super.

I'm not a Goxpert so Go (see what I did there?) easy on me..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *If* you are not interested only in a "how many seconds are in a 30 day month" than the answer is constant and 30*24*60*60 is perfectly fine and totally elegant. Anything else is just wired.

Comment: I completely agree with Volker, there's nothing elegant about jumping through all sorts of hoops just to perform a few simple multiplications. 30*24*60*60 is as elegant as it gets. It's immediately obvious to anyone reading the code and it doesn't involve needless function calls and package imports.

Comment: Ok thanks, use this for 30 day Period and @Danilo answer for a spesifc month secounds

Answer (score 6):

Use time.Duration Seconds() :

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    m := time.Hour * 24 * 30
    fmt.Println("In float: ", m.Seconds())
    fmt.Println("In int: ", int(m.Seconds()))
}
```

Example on [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/UmgRBxIg5z)

Comment: Thanks @wlredeye that did the trick, wish there was some way to get rid of the `24 * 30 ` also

Comment: time.Hour is the biggest constant representing duration constants https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration . So I think you can't avoid using multiply

Answer (score 4):

If you do care about the different days in months, you can use `time.Sub` to get the duration:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
)

func secondsInMonth(y int, m time.Month) int {
  start := time.Date(y, m, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
  end := time.Date(y, m+1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
  return int(end.Sub(start).Seconds())
}

func main() {
  month := time.February
  year := 2016

  fmt.Printf("Days in %s %d: %d\n", month, year, secondsInMonth(year, month))
}
```

If you dont care just do `30*24*60*60`. Thats as elegant as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the previous answers, but if you really want to remove the 24 * 30 it is possible.

Just goofing around; time.Time has some nice comparison features so this is another option:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    now := time.Now()

    // the current month in seconds - can vary
    duration := now.AddDate(0, 1, 0).Sub(now)
    fmt.Println("In int: ", int(duration.Seconds()))

    // similar, but exactly 30 days
    duration := now.AddDate(0, 0, 30).Sub(now)
    fmt.Println("In int: ", int(duration.Seconds()))
}
```

Example on [playground](http://play.golang.org/p/PvvpqK-PpW)

Comment: By accident,  you picked a 30-day month. "In the playground the time begins at 2009-11-10 23:00:00 UTC " [About the Playground](http://play.golang.org/). See [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/18HpvxlAEO).

Comment: Added an exactly 30 day variant

Comment: @peterSO I don't think you understood foo's intention. He wanted to point out that the AddDate function adds exactly 1 month to the given time. It's a perfect solution. It handles all kinds of month lengths.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are only having 30 day months, we have a constant here and there is absolutely no need for any calculation. Using basic maths, we simplify

```
30*24*60*60
```

to

```
const secsInMonth = 2592000
```